# Which algrorithm and mathematical logic is used behind scipy.spatial.KDTree(curve)

Tags: python, scipy, kdtree, scipy-spatial

I am finding the shortest distance to the point using this

```
#find the nearest point and shortest distance 
curve=np.column_stack((curve_mrds,curve_nrds)) # <-- the coordinates of the curve 
point = points_2  # <-- the point to find
#The distance of the point to the curve
dist=spatial.KDTree(curve).query(point)[0] #<-- The distance of the point to the curve.
```

The things i want to know, if possible with references
-the mathematical equations/logic behind the spatial.KDTree(curve).query(point)[0]
-the algorithm behind the spatial.KDTree(curve).query(point)[0]

I have looked in the help as well, but it does not state the mathematical notation or reference to the original algorithm.
I originally need references for publications.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation makes this very clear.  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html

> **Notes**
>
> The algorithm used is described in Maneewongvatana and Mount 1999. The general idea is that the kd-tree is a binary tree, each of whose nodes represents an axis-aligned hyperrectangle. Each node specifies an axis and splits the set of points based on whether their coordinate along that axis is greater than or less than a particular value.